# Won't add new objects to an array after removing all objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

This is my array

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *searchResults;
```

I initialized it in viewDidLoad function. I want to remove all objects from this array when current input in search bar is changed and add populate it using new elements. 
But when I do

```
[self.searchResults removeAllObjects];
```

It won't add new elements. same goes with returning an array to self.searchResults

But when I don't remove elements from an array and append elements, it adds elements with no problem. I'm really having a hard time figuring out what's wrong.

viewDidLoad func

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self searchHandler:self.searchBar];
}
```

here is adding new elements.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getProductList: (NSString *)text withArray: (NSMutableArray *) arrayResult{
[self.searchResults removeAllObjects];
[manager POST:url parameters:parameter
        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
            NSLog(@"Length: %lu", (unsigned long)[responseObject count]);
            int length = [responseObject count];
            NSString *key;
            for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
                key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
                [self.searchResults addObject:responseObject[key]];
            }
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];
}
```

checking the array

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    NSLog(@"changed text: %@", searchText);
    //[searchResults removeAllObjects];
    self.searchResults = [self getProductList:searchText withArray:self.searchResults];
    NSLog(@"Length of current array: %lu", (unsigned long)[self.searchResults count]);
    for (NSString *item in self.searchResults) {
        NSLog(@"%@", item);
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
 }
```

Comment: are you sure that this: `responseObject[key]` is returning something meaningful ?

Comment: @JulianKról yes. It's returning some strings.

Comment: self.searchResults is it not nil while trying to add something?

Comment: @JulianKról I checked it. it's not nil.

Comment: then it is weird, looks like you are not telling us the full story :)

Comment: `searchResults` is `nil` and never had anything in it to begin with.

Comment: I tried initializing it in init function that I overwritten and viewDidLoad function. Also checked it whether its nil or not in searchbar event listener function. Also I tried adding object to the array without removeAllObjects message and it was adding objects. @HotLicks

Comment: It's nil, trust me.  Stupid question:  How many different places do you do `[[MyViewController alloc] init...]`?

Comment: Remember, Objective-C will silently ignore a nil pointer in many circumstances.

Comment: @HotLicks only once in another view controller that has scroll view to jump between 2 view controllers. I also tried initializing in the latter function, which is basically called on every time when change occurs in search bar.

Comment: So nowhere do you create an instance of the class so you can set/access one of its properties?

Comment: There is an instance of the class in another view controller which is called when application is started. @HotLicks

Comment: Where are you inspecting `searchResults` to determine that nothing is being added?

Comment: You understand that if you create two different instances of the same class, they do not magically "share" the same properties, but each has it's own set. You can't initialize a property in one instance and then operate on that property in another instance.

Comment: I'm betting on a different common problem than you are, @HotLicks: not understanding that the completion Block is asynchronous and looking at the array immediately after the `POST:parameters:success:failure:` call.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - Yep, that's another possibility.  He doesn't log immediately after setting values into the array so we have no indication what's going on.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I added how I checked the array.

Comment: Okay, now how does that connect to the other snippet?

Comment: @JoshCaswell they are methods of one class and getProductList is called every time when there is a change in searchbar input. getProductList removes all previous objects from the array and add new elements to that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set searchResults

```
  self.searchResults = [self getProductList:searchText withArray:self.searchResults];
```

But `getProductList` doesn't return an array.  Aren't you getting a warning?  If not, I suspect you are just setting it to nil on the return

Also, `getProductList` is asynchronous, but you are just trying to load table data as soon as it returns.

Do something more like this instead:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getProductList: (NSString *)text withArray: (NSMutableArray *) arrayResult{
[self.searchResults removeAllObjects];
[manager POST:url parameters:parameter
        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
            NSLog(@"Length: %lu", (unsigned long)[responseObject count]);
            int length = [responseObject count];
            NSString *key;
            for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
                key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
                [self.searchResults addObject:responseObject[key]];
            }

            [self.tableView reloadData];

        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];
}


- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
  [self getProductList:searchText withArray:self.searchResults];    
}
```

This should be cleaned up more (remove the withArray parameter -- you don't even use it).

Just make sure `self.searchResults` is not nil at this point.

Comment: I tried initializing new array and assigning to self.searchResults but it still didn't work. I directly removed elements from the array in function as well.

Comment: The function `getProductList:withArray` isn't returning anything -- don't assign to `searchResults` in `searchBar:textDidChange:`  That whole function is a mess -- you pass in the output array (arrayResult), you update self.searchResults directly, and you expect to return an array.  Pick one of those.

Comment: Oh I should've just added [self.tableView reloadData] after adding elements. Thanks!!!

Comment: AND AND AND -- don't overwrite `self.searchResults` by assigning the return (when you don't return anything)

Comment: yeah. I changed it to void now.